# iOS CGContextDrawPDFPage memory not thread safe

Tags: ios, pdf, memory, draw, memory-leaks

When i draw a PDF i saw from instruments that if the CGContextDrawPDFPage method is not called from main thread, creates a leak in memory.

Someone has encountered the same problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i have the same problem.have you found any solution out for this problem.I am calling CGContextDrawPDFPage on a background thread and instruments is showing 100% leak on that line.

Answer (score 0):

It’s been a while, but I recall that the PDF functions involved a fair amount of lazy instantiation or caching. Is Instruments showing a true leak, or just allocations that don’t go away?

I remember getting concerned about memory bloat, until I realized it went away when I released the higher-level objects (CGPDFDocumentRef, I think).